# How to delete a google calendar list feed with zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've seen plenty of tutorials on how to delete calendar events with zend framework but none on actually deleting calendars themselves? (ie calendar lists). Is it possible? How would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it took me a while but I managed to solve it myself. Here's a tutorial on how to do it http://flynsarmy.com/2010/10/deleting-a-google-calendar-with-php